# How do I develop an audio streaming application in android?

Tags: java, android, audio, stream

I want to develop an Audio Streaming Android application, I don't need it just for streaming music from a certain URL, I need it to enable anyone create an account and go live with a Live Audio Session that will be published for everyone.

For example, if there are two people in the session (Speaker and Listener), the Speaker presses a button and goes live and the Listener presses a button and joins the session!

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? Is "RTSP" included in this? How do I use it in my application and implement it? Is there any tutorial to help me? Must I develop a website to use it for streaming or is an android application and a streaming server enough?

Example of a related Application: Mixler.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three options, the first two would be the simplest, they would cost you more but they probably come with the least headache.

[**Castasy**](http://castpub.com) includes:

- a live streaming server
- a website
- an android app (pre-built and they include the source code)
- a tutorial (showing you how to build everything from scratch)
- lifetime upgrades

[**Muvi**](https://www.muvi.com/signup) includes:

- Free 14 day trial
- Website, Mobile Apps & TV Apps (with additional charges)
- Cloud Hosting
- Servers
- [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)
- [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) (with additional charges)
- Online Video Player
- Monetization (because you may in the future want to have a 'pro' version and a free version that has advertisements)
- And much more...

---

The last option would be for you to build everything yourself; you would need to:

- Use a [cloud hosted server](https://www.wowza.com/solutions/streaming-types/audio-only-streaming) that comes with audio streaming
- Or setup a local audio streaming server (you can try [Broadwave](http://www.nchsoftware.com/howto/how_to_create_a%20streaming_audio_server_using_broadwave.html) or take a look at this [article](http://letzgro.net/blog/how-to-make-a-streaming-server-that-will-meet-your-business-needs/))
- Or set up your own online server so you can communicate with that server to *GET* the contents using [REST](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-from-scratch-using-rest-apis--cms-27117)
- Get familiar with Digital Rights Management (DRM) and [incorporate it](https://source.android.com/devices/drm) into the app to avoid getting sued over broadcasting copyrighted content.
- Enable authentication (for user registration/login), you can try Firebase which comes with [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), etc.
- Maintain, modify and support the app.

There are more options out there, you can take a look at each one and see which you one you like.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, wowza GoCoder it's a nice service but it's fine to me ?
can i use wowza to accomplish my goals ?
accomplish " Speaker " to go live with a session ?
and " Listener " can join it ? if u can give me tutorial to do **exactly** this ?

Comment: yes, wowza should be able to do what u need, they have lots of documentations on how to go about using different features especially their live audio stream. u can also reach out to them at `https://www.wowza.com/contact` and describe ur project and see what they say.